# Shimano STX rear shifter, broken spring

Tags: shimano, repair, shifter

I have to repair a Shimano STX shifter 7 speed (from a Raleigh MT200 bike from 1995). It has a broken spring, and I am almost sure that is the only thing to be repaired.

It is similar to that pictured in https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~geoff/deoredx/reductions/P2004.09.08-10.17.55-3814-labeled.02.html

[image: shimano shifter exploded view]

I found a disassembly of the brifter ST-EF28-Left. In this figure, the broken spring would be "Coil spring", I guess.

[image]

I would be happy to get a minimally invasive solution.

Is there any chance of getting the replacement part? Where from?

Otherwise, I would get a new shifter/brake, only right side. I found several options. Can anyone let me know which is the order from lower end to higher end?

- Acera SL-M310
- ST-EF51
- ST-EF28 (my spring is similar to the "Coil spring") [here](http://exaphone.toocan.com/2013/05/shimano-st-ef28-combined-front.html)
- [SB-CT91](http://www.ebay.com/itm/SHIMANO-GEAR-BRAKE-LEVER-7-speed-black-silver-RIGHT-SIDE-SB-CT91-new-/171936326890)
- STX (from ebay, e.g.)
- Some V-brake option (see [Shimano integrated shifter/brake: Cantilever compatible with V-Brake?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/36588/shimano-integrated-shifter-brake-cantilever-compatible-with-v-brake))
- Some other 8 speed option (it is ok, as per links below).

[Can you use a 8 speed Shimano shifter with a 7 speed cassette?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/8909/can-you-use-a-8-speed-shimano-shifter-with-a-7-speed-cassette)

[8 speed shifter with 7 speed cassette](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/21894/8-speed-shifter-with-7-speed-cassette)

Other useful links:

http://www.4bc.org/instruc/shimano/rapid_fire_shifter.html

Comment: I embedded the image, but there are three springs shown - which one? But in general, second hand shifters are cheap and you can probably find a working copy of your one, or just a replacement 7 speed shifter. If you get the same one you have spare parts, but that makes it harder to find the replacement.

Comment: Gidday and welcome to SE bicycles.  I think you'll be better off finding a replacement shifter.  This one pictured is an indexed shifter, and mine cost around $35 NZ from the LBS.  The only reason for fixing your one is if you're after pure originality.  Your LBS may even have something that looks similar.

Comment: My suggestion is to either buy the Altus SL-M310 (which is 7 speed) or a friction shifter. The ST-EF51 is garbage -- I had one for all of about 2 days before it started acting up. Microshift TS38-7 will also work but I don't know of the quality. There isn't really a point in servicing shifters beyond WD-40 flushing if necessary unless they're expensive or have sentimental value.

Comment: @Mσᶎ - Thanks for embedding the image. Even though the picture does not correspond exactly to an STX, I am almost certain it is the downshift return spring. In the likely case of not getting the spring (which might be cheaper and easier to repair) I would get a part.

Comment: @Criggie - I live in Argentina... Not that much variety, and prices about doubling+ Amazon/ebay.

Comment: @sancho.s I live in New Zealand, where everything is expensive.  You should try the LBS... One that is not targeted at sporty or road racer types.  You will be pleasantly surprised how expensive they are not.

Comment: @sancho.s if you are still looking I can most likely provide you with a replacement unit

Comment: @Mikkel - I only now see your comment. I certainly appreciate your kindness!
I got a replacement pair from ebay, about $30, and a friend brought it to me from US.
But if you still have them, please let me know. Thanks!