# How to collect Shimano ALTUS parts together?

Tags: shimano, shifter

[image]
[image][image]
So today this morning i was trying to shift with the front shifter, but after a while it was just shifting on nothing i mean was not working then i tried to push it hard and then everything came out. I've taken some picture to show you guys if i can fix it or it's totally broken ?
And if i can, can you help me out to collect them together again ?

Comment: Its not the same shifter but this may help  http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/36577/shimano-stx-rear-shifter-broken-spring    If you pushed hard, it moved suddenly, and the internals may have failed, and a new pod shifter would be much more reliable.   For some things its worth replacing with a new part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shifters are notoriously hard to reassemble, and if it came to pieces unexpectedly it's going to be hard to know whether you've got everything. You also don't know (until you've put all the effort in to try and fix it) whether the reason it gave you trouble in the first place is something you can fix. An Altus shifter shouldn't be expensive so it's probably best to replace it.